# Cannot pick up packets with UdpClient.Receive, but wireshark sees them

Tags: c#, udp, embedded, wireshark, udpclient

I'm doing some embedded development, and I'm sending udp packets from the board to a simple listener written in C#
However, the C# client never receives anything, despite the packets being detected by Wireshark.

When the board is sending messages and the listener is not running, I see alternating UDP packets and ICMP error packets in wireshark. When I start the listener, the error packets disappear, but nothing is received.

I have tried sending from another computer instead, and this works fine. And comparing the packets from the PC with those from the board reveals no apparent differences.

Screencap of packet from board in Wireshark: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuPIJ.png

I'm really lost here, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps post the code for your C# listener? Try using a different port. How about sending data the other way? You can also type netstat -an in a windows console to view open sockets.. could be useful

Comment: I don't have this problem anymore, after I created a new, more thoroughly written client. I'm not sure what the problem was, but I suspect It might have been a port issue. Thanks for your time though